# I'm having trouble with turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i run the code, the turtle window opens up and then nothing happens. After a few seconds my cursor becomes the loading cursor and I am forced into killing the program. What's wrong with my code here ?

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.speed(10)
for x in range(1,100):
    y=random.randint(000000,999999)
    y=str(y)
    while not len(y)==0:
        y="0"+y
    y="#"+y
    turtle.color(y)
    turtle.circle(40+x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You had an endless loop in your program

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.speed(10)
for x in range(1,100):
    y=random.randint(000000,999999)
    y=str(y)
    print(1)
    while len(y)<6: # was always true: not len(y)==0
        print(3)    # would print a lot of 3
        y="0"+y
    y="#"+y
    print(2)
    turtle.color(y)
    turtle.circle(40+x)
```

I recommend adding print statements to your program if things like these happen. Then you can track where it hangs. Also using a debugger can help finding out.